# A doubly linked list with index pointer?

Tags: python, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

[doubly linked list with index pointer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdiWK.jpg)This is what we call it in the class but I didn’t find anything similar on the internet and this is the example code but I don’t understand the way it works, if you can give me a visual of the linked list created this way, that would be great

this is the code(in case that you couldn't open the picture):

```
class CursorList:
def __init__(self,max=100):
    self.max=max
    self.next=[None]*self.max
    self.element=[None]*self.max
    self.prev=[None]*self.max
    self.avail=0
    self.head=None
    self.size=0
    for i in range (self.max-1):
        self.next[i]=i+1
def allocate(self):
    if self.avail is None:
        raise Exception('out of space')
    x=self.avail
    self.avail=self.next[self.avail]
    return x
def free(self,x):
    self.next[x]=self.avail
    self.avail=x
def is_empty(self):
    return self.size==0
def insert_first(self,e):
    index=self.allocate()
    self.next[index]=self.head
    self.element[index]=e
    self.prev[index]=None
    if not self.is_empty():
        self.prev[self.head]=index
    self.head=index
    self.size+=1
def delete_first(self):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise Exception('List is empty')
    index=self.head
    e=self.element[index]
    self.head=self.next[self.head]
    self.size-=1
    self.free(index)
    return e
```

Comment: Please post code as text (formatted). See also [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

It is a regular [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) data structure such that the pointing to the next and previous node will be done by index. So, it looks like [the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) (except you need to see the index of the element as a pointer to that element):

[image]